# hidden g++ reference error

Tags: c++, gcc, reference

Compiling with GCC 4.8.1 (MinGW) with command: `g++ -o test.exe test.cpp`

**test.cpp**:

```
#include <iostream>

int a = 1, b = 2;

void F()
{
    int &r = a;
    std::cout << r;
    r = b;
    std::cout << r;
}

int main ( int, char** )
{
    F();
    F();
    return 0;
}
```

The expected output is: **1212**, but real is: **1222**

It works as expected when `r` is defined as pointer.

```
void F()
{
    int *r = &a;
    std::cout << *r;
    r = &b;
    std::cout << *r;
}
```

Does someone have any idea where is "the key from the tent"?

Comment: "The expected output is: 1212" - NO - it's 1222. In the second example you're simply assigning pointers, to get similar behavior you need to do `*r = b;` instead of `r = &b;`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the example with a pointer:

```
r = &b;
```

This re-seats the pointer `r` to point to `b`.  In the example with the reference:

```
r = b;
```

You probably think that this is analogous to the example with the pointer, but it is not.  References are not re-seatable the way pointers are. Once they are initialized, they become aliases for the thing which they reference.  So the line above is exactly equivalent to this:

```
a = b;
```

That is, it copies the value stored in `b` over to `a`.

The reference example is could be written like this:

```
void F()
{
    std::cout << a;
    a = b;
    std::cout << a;
}
```

While the pointer example could be written like this:

```
void F()
{
    std::cout << a;    
    std::cout << b;
}
```

Comment: You catch my mistake correctly. Thanks. It also means that there is no way to redefine reference to point to other object.

Comment: @RaychoRaykov: That's correct, and basically the purpose of a reference in the language.

Answer (score 1):

Your "problem" is the following line:

```
int &r = a;
```

This will create a so called reference pointing to `a`. While references don't require additional logic when accessing them (i.e. dereferencing; compared to pointers), they still work the same way behind the scenes.

So once you hit the line

```
r = b;
```

You'll actually use the reference and update the value of `a`. In this case `r` never has it's own value. It will always point at `a` and essentially be an alias.

In your second example, this is different. The line

```
int *r = &a;
```

creates a pointer pointing at `a` and

```
r = &b;
```

will reassign that address, making the pointer now point at `b`.

In short, when you assign some other **value (address) to a pointer**, you **change the pointer** and it will point somewhere else. However, when assigning a new value to a reference, you're actually updating the inital **value** where it's **referencing** to, **not the reference itself**.

Answer (score 0):

```
//global variables! remember that this will be like a state
//and will be freed on (data?BSS?stack?) only after end of program.
int a = 1, b = 2;

void F()
{
    //You are referencing here,
    //meaning, once you change the referee ( r )
    //the reference will changed permanently.
    //Permanently because you are referring to a global variable.
    int &r = a;        

    std::cout << r;

    //You have changed the value of ( r )
    //forever!

    r = b;   //I think you are assuming the you have changed the reference address here?
    std::cout << r;
}
```

---

```
void F()
{
    //You have declared and initialized a pointer
    //that points to global variable.
    //w/c means you can also change its value forever!
    int *r = &a;
    std::cout << *r;

    //You have changed the ( r ) address pointing to, not its value!
    r = &b;
    std::cout << *r;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Your code is absolutely fine and it's working according to your instruction.
Suppose a variable has 1000 address b variable 1004 address, now your first line is  
         int &r = a;
that means r has 1000 address  and you did cout<< r //print 1
In second statement  r = b that means 1000 address hold value of b means 2;
Now , your scenario has been changed 1000---> 2 and 1004--->2 

and again you are calling F();
that's why compiler print twice 2 value. . There is a concept referencing in c++. Hope it  
would be useful for u
```